# Расположение окна Toplevel по центру в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть код, в котором автоматически центрируется главное окно программы (функция windows_to_center). Входные данные: ширина и высота, если задано по нулям, то размер окна будет зависеть от содержимого. При этом положение окна всегда будет по центру. Также эту функцию я применяю и к окну справки Toplevel в функции about, в этом случае положение по центру устанавливается при задании ширины и высоты, а без установки этих параметров виджет не центрируется, находится чуть дальше от центра. Где я допустил ошибку? Ранее использовал процедурный подход и такой ошибки не наблюдал. Готов выслушать любую критику по своему коду.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
First GUI App
"""

from tkinter import *

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        main_menu= Menu(self.master)
        master.configure(menu=main_menu)
        second_item = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
        main_menu.add_cascade(label='Справка',menu=second_item)
        second_item.add_command(label='О программе',command=self.about)

    def about(self):
        top = Toplevel()
        top.title('О программе')
        top.geometry(self.windows_to_center(0,0))
        msg = Message(top, justify="center", text=__doc__).grid()

    def windows_to_center(self,pw,ph):
        if pw==0 and ph==0:
            geometry = "+{}+{}".format(int((self.master.winfo_screenwidth() - self.master.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2), int((self.master.winfo_screenheight() - self.master.winfo_reqheight()) / 2))
        else:
            geometry = '{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(pw, ph, int(self.master.winfo_screenwidth()//2 - (pw/2)), int(self.master.winfo_screenheight()//2 - (ph/2)))
        return geometry


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainroot=Tk()
    app=MainWindow(mainroot)
    mainroot.geometry(app.windows_to_center(400,300))
    mainroot.grid()
    mainroot.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что winfo_reqwidth и winfo_reqhight выдавали некорректные значения. Необходимо было обновить содержимое окна, а только потом измерять и изменять положение окна. Правда при таком раскладе на моей машине я замечал, как окно из одного места переезжает в другое (в центр). Это было заметно невооруженным глазом. Пришлось искать другой способ переместить окно и оно было найдено: tk::PlaceWindow.

Весь код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Тут должно быть очень много текста, лишь для заполнения окна.
"""

from tkinter import *

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        main_menu = Menu(self.master)
        master.configure(menu=main_menu)
        second_item = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
        main_menu.add_cascade(label='Справка',menu=second_item)
        second_item.add_command(label='О программе',command=self.about)

    def about(self):
        top = Toplevel()
        top.title('О программе')
        Message(top, justify="center", text=__doc__).grid()
        self.windows_to_center(top)

    def windows_to_center(self,thiswindow,pw=0,ph=0):
        if pw != 0 and ph != 0: 
            thiswindow.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(pw, ph, int(thiswindow.winfo_screenwidth()//2 - (pw/2)), int(thiswindow.winfo_screenheight()//2 - (ph/2))))
        else:
            self.master.eval('tk::PlaceWindow {} center'.format(thiswindow))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainroot = Tk()
    app = MainWindow(mainroot)
    app.windows_to_center(mainroot, 500, 100)
    mainroot.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте как нибудь так.
Т.е. по сути у вас одна функции отвечает за централизацию виджета на экране (т.е. по сути координаты остануться не изменными), а вторая функция распределение размера виджета, по сути вы изобретаете велосипед потому что при помощи `wm_geometry` вы можете задать позицию виджета а при помощи `geometry` вы можете указать размер виджета.

```
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        main_menu = Menu(self.master)
        master.configure(menu=main_menu)
        second_item = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
        main_menu.add_cascade(label='Справка',menu=second_item)
        second_item.add_command(label='О программе',command=self.about)

    def about(self):
        top = Toplevel()
        top.title('О программе')
        top.geometry(self.windows_size(0, 0))
        top.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x_center, y_center))
        msg = Message(top, justify="center", text=__doc__).grid()

    def windows_size(self, w, h):
        return "{}x{}".format(w, h) if w and h else "200x200"

def windows_to_center():
    x = (mainroot.winfo_screenwidth() - mainroot.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
    y = (mainroot.winfo_screenheight() - mainroot.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
    return x, y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainroot = Tk()
    app = MainWindow(mainroot)
    x_center, y_center = windows_to_center()
    mainroot.geometry(app.windows_size(400, 400))
    mainroot.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x_center, y_center))
    mainroot.grid()
    mainroot.mainloop()
```

P.s функцию сравнение значения размера окна можно сократить до

```
windows_size = lambda w, h: "{}x{}".format(w, h) if w and h else "200x200"
```

Comment: К сожалению способ мне не подошел. wm_geometry считает координаты окна без учета его фактического размера. Либо я чего-то не понимаю. В своей функции '{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(pw, ph, int(self.master.winfo_screenwidth()//2 - (pw/2)), int(self.master.winfo_screenheight()//2 - (ph/2))), у меня есть учет размера окна, правда в текущей записи он не всегда работает. Мне нужно обновить пост, чтобы дать больше информации.